# Show that a category of algebras has the epimorphism surjectivity property iff no algebra has a proper epic subalgebra

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

Show that a category of algebras (and their homomorphisms) has the
epimorphism surjectivity property iff no algebra has a proper epic subalgebra where the epimorphism surjectivity property (ES) means surjective homomorphisms are equivalent to epis and a subalgebra **B** $\leq$ **A** is epic whenever two homomorphisms $f,g:$**A**$ \to $**C** coincide on B implies they are equal.

Edit: The forward direction has been handled in the comments (by contrapositive). For the reverse direction, I was thinking of using a similar idea.

Comment: The key word here is "proper". It precisely means that the inclusion morphism is not surjective.

Comment: @CaptainLama Ok so you are saying, if we consider the inclusion $i:B \to A$, if $fi = gi$ then $f=g$ so it's epi but since B is proper it cannot be onto.

Comment: Well it's epi by hypothesis, since it says "a proper epic subalgebra". And yes, since the inclusion $B\subset A$ is proper, it exactly means it is not unto.

Comment: @CaptainLama  Oh right, that makes sense. For the reverse direction can we use the inclusion morphism again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the forward direction by contrapositive, suppose $\exists$ **B** < **A** s.t. **B** is epic. Consider the inclusion morphism $i:$**B** $\to$ **A**. Then $i$ is epi but cannot be onto since **B** is proper. Thus epi $\nRightarrow$ onto and so the category does not have ES.

Conversely, suppose epi $\nRightarrow$ onto. Let **B** $\leq$ **A**, $i:$**B** $\to$ **A** be the inclusion map which is epi but not onto, and $fi=gi$. Then $f=g$ so **B** is epic but since $i$ isn't onto we must have **B** < **A**. Hence there exists a proper epic subalgebra.